# Why are you abiding by WPSE mods asking you to close my question?

Tags: discussion

Why is Gerald doing what WPSE mods asked him to do? Closing my question for no reason?

[What are some good Nginx rate limits for WordPress websites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1157088/what-are-some-good-nginx-rate-limits-for-wordpress-websites)

Very tired of the petty power trips and egos that destroy the quality of SE network, this is why so many people have stopped participating here, because they must waste time dealing with this drama all the time...

Comment: Update: I just flagged a dozen questions similar to mine, hopefully Gerald will immediately BAN these questions from the ServerFault community, to prove that I was not being personally targeted after he chatted with Tom from WPSE.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, I'm being sarcastic, I don't want any questions banned... in fact, I think the threshold for getting a question closed should be more like 5+ votes to avoid high-rep trolls from the WPSE community that don't like me for some reason following me around SE and flagging all my posts...

Answer (score 5):

You say there is discussion elsewhere about this question, but even if you had linked to it, it wouldn't be relevant.  So far, two users here have voted to close the question - for two different and arguably valid reasons.

The only drama is what you're creating yourself: your deleted comment on the question is inappropriate, the over-the-top statements here aren't warranted, and flagging old posts to make a point will result in a suspension if you continue.

If you think your question as asked is appropriate, you can leave it and see if there are any additional close votes cast.  If you want to modify it based on the comments you've received, you can do that even if it does get closed.  Either way, you should focus on the question itself.  Questions/complaints about the overall nature of multiple SE sites should go somewhere else: meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was literally told to flag old posts, the drama is from bored high-rep users and mods, although mostly from WPSE who followed me over here. The reasons given to close my questions and down-vote me are irrelevant because they are disingenuous.